# Linker Command Failed with Exit Code 1 When Excluding arm64 Architecture on Simulator with Xcode 15

Tags: ios, arm64, swift-package-manager, xcode15

I've been developing an iOS app using the AppAuth library, managed through Swift Package Manager. Until now, I've been using Xcode version 14.3.1 on an M2 Mac, and I have been successfully excluding the `arm64` architecture for the simulator by specifying 'Excluded Architectures' in my project settings.

However, after updating to Xcode 15, while still needing to exclude the `arm64` architecture for the simulator due to technical requirements, I encounter a linker command failure when compiling for the simulator. The error message is as follows:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file '.../AppAuth.o', missing required architecture 'x86_64' in file '.../AppAuth.o' (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file '.../AppAuthCore.o', missing required architecture 'x86_64' in file '.../AppAuthCore.o' (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_OIDIDToken", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I don't exclude the `arm64` architecture, everything compiles fine, but I cannot move forward without excluding it for the simulator.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue after updating to Xcode 15? Any suggestions on how to resolve this error while still excluding the `arm64` architecture for the simulator?